# keep popover stopped after click using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I have a problem that I am unable to solve. I need a popover appear when I click on the star that is in the image below:
[image]

The code being used:

```
$('area').popover({
        measure: 'img.image-map',
        mouseOffset: 20,
        container: 'body',
        followMouse: true,
        html: true,
        trigger: 'click'
    });
```

But has some problems:
1 - popover are following the mouse. With this I can not use the scroll inside the popover.
2 - when I put just click does not work because the area is mapped, then the popover appears out of the picture

html:

```
<li class="bg bg-casa">     
    <a href="#" class="popover-area" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto right"></a>

    <img class="image-map" src="images/arvore-presepio.png" alt="" usemap="#MapCasa" />

    <map name="MapCasa" id="MapCasa">
    <!-- Árvore(estrela) -->
    <area id="arvore" data-content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="231,81,252,51,252,39,247,40,248,29,242,22,251,21,255,13,259,22,273,21,266,41,261,50,269,63" />
</map>
```

when not using that script and put a simple click it misses alignment:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `followMouse` to `false`? This might solve your problem of the popover following your mouse.

Comment: don`t work! see -> http://s14.postimg.org/3nr360qg1/Screen_Shot_2015_11_05_at_11_48_09.png

lost align and popover down

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: much code to use jsfiddle